# Make ReSharper run test using .net Framework 3.5

Tags: testing, .net-3.5, resharper, mstest

I am currently testing sharepoint components using msTest, which works nicely. However, when I run my testst using ReSharper all tests fail because ReSharper (6) is running the tests using .net Framework 4.

Is it possible to configure ReSharper (6) to run all tests using .net Framework 3.5 (CLR 2)?

Comment: Have you seen this issue: [ReSharper 6 and CLR2 support](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-274995)?

Comment: Do you use *Visual Studio 2010*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you use ***Visual Studio 2010***: This is an issue in Visual Studio, not in ReSharper.
See Microsoft's answer:

> Hi Chris,
>
> In VS 2010, the Test Team has made a painful yet concious decision to
>   not support multi-targeting. **As a result, test projects will be
>   upgraded to target .NET 4.0**. We have made some, workarounds to allow a
>   VB Test Project that references an MVC code under test to not upgrade,
>   but in general, all others will be retargeted. The VB 3.5 Test Project
>   sill has some limitations and will always run tests in a .NET 4.0
>   process. Also, you cannot take the tests and run them on a VS 2008
>   test system.
>
> Thanks Visual Studio Product Team.

in site http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/514130/visual-studio-2010-beta-2-silently-upgrades-mstest-test-projects-to-net-4-0.